# What is Fixed Length Over TCP?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

My Scenario

I am new to socket based programming or network protocols like TCP. I have a server which works based on the protocol - **Fixed Length Over TCP**. I have a sample client side application which reads a TXT file and send it to the server via socket.

I am trying to replicate the server with a simple application which receives request from client over socket and responds to client.

My client and server application is mentioned below.

**Client side code**

```
 String host = "localhost";

        int port = 19997;

    StringBuffer instr = new StringBuffer();
    String TimeStamp;
    System.out.println("SocketClient initialized");

    try {
      InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
      Socket connection = new Socket(address, port);

       BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.
          getOutputStream());
      OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, "US-ASCII");

      TimeStamp = new java.util.Date().toString();

      String process = "01234"+  (char) 13;

      osw.write(process);
      osw.flush();

      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(connection.
          getInputStream());

      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bis, "US-ASCII");

      int c,d=0;
      try
      {
          if(isr.ready())
          {
          }
          else
              System.out.println("NO RESPONSE");
      while (( (c = isr.read()) != 13) && d<4)
      {
        instr.append( (char) c);
        System.out.println("Inside Loop - "+instr);
        d++;
      }}
      catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
      {
          System.out.println("OOM ERROR - "+e);
          System.out.println(instr);
      }
      /** Close the socket connection. */
      connection.close();
      System.out.println(instr);

    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {
     System.out.println("Unknown Host Exception: " + e);
    }
    catch(ConnectException e)
    {
     System.out.println("ConnectException: " + e);
    }
    catch(Exception e1)
    {
     System.out.println("Exception: " + e1);
    }
```

**Server side code**

```
        try{
      socket1 = new ServerSocket(port);
      System.out.println("SingleSocketServer Initialized");
      int character;

    while (true) {
        connection = socket1.accept();

        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        process = new StringBuffer();
        while((character = isr.read()) != 13) {
          process.append((char)character);
          System.out.println("Inside while loop");
        }
        System.out.println("Hello"+process);
        //need to wait 10 seconds for the app to update database
        try {
          Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
        TimeStamp = new java.util.Date().toString();
        //String returnCode = "SingleSocketServer repsonded at "+ TimeStamp + (char) 13;
        String returnCode = "56789"+  (char) 13;
        BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "US-ASCII");
        osw.write(returnCode);
        osw.flush();
     }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {}
      try {
        connection.close();
      }
      catch (IOException e) {}
  }
```

this is working fine.

My question is

1. What i have implemented, is this - Fixed Length Over TCP ? If not, how to implement a sample client and server java application for the same ?
2. How is fixed Length over TCP different from what i have implemented ?

Comment: Get rid of the `ready()` test. It's pointless. The following read will block as necessary.

Comment: @EJP, can you please elaborate ?